# Open menu when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open menu when hovering the mouse over it , I tried to edit it from css but nothing there also I tried in the HTML aalso nothing happened so I think its something with the JavaScript code. and I'm not that familiar with JS so I need your help please.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="allwrap">

    <nav class="nav-menux">
        <div class="menu-menu-container">
          <ul id="left-navigation" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1439" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1439"><a href="#">our leatest</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-portfolio current-menu-item menu-item-62"><a href="#">our work</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1416" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1416"><a href="#">decor</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1409"><a href="#">wood work</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
```

this is my JS code that I use:

```
            var menuids=["left-navigation"]

            function buildsubmenus(){
            for (var x=0; x<menuids.length; x++){
              var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[x]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
                for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
                ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="left-navigation-sub"
                    if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[x]) //if this is a first level submenu
                        ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px" //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
                    else //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
                      ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth+"px" //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
                ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block"
                }
                ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
                }
                }
                    for (var t=ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--){ //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
                    ultags[t].style.visibility="visible"
                    ultags[t].style.display="none"
                    }
              }
            }

            if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", buildsubmenus, false)
            else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", buildsubmenus)

        </script>
```

Comment: Can you get your html code? i think best it create css rule.

Comment: Dropdown menu can be designed with CSS and HTML. Add your markup here or on jsfiddle. You can also search for the same as there are too many tutorials for the same.

Comment: This the way to hell. Throw it out and start again. It must work on pure css. Like 

    `#sideMenu li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }`

Comment: I added the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pure css.

here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="left-navigation" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1439" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1439"><a href="#">our leatest</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-portfolio current-menu-item menu-item-62"><a href="#">our work</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1416" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1416"><a href="#">decor</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1409"><a href="#">wood work</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#left-navigation{
  width:20px; /* give it a width to hover*/
  background-color:green;
  overflow:hidden; /* overflow as hidden so content don't mess with the height of menu*/
}

#left-navigation li{
  width:100px;       /* give it a default width for li*/
  visibility: hidden;/* hide content */
}

#left-navigation:hover{
  width:100px; /* on hover change width*/
}

#left-navigation:hover li{
  visibility:visible; /*on hover, show li*/
}
```

And here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfq05ebw/)

Comment: it make since but can you take a look in my CSS it's little bet deferent: [CSS LINK from My Website](http://www.benaacom.net/wp-content/themes/arkitek/style.css)

Comment: Can you give me a link to where your menu is used?

Comment: www.benaacom.net (It's an Arabic website) you can find it on the left side upper corner

Comment: Hover won't work since the button is much far away from the menu itself

Comment: is there any solution to do that ? I can change the button location no problem.

Comment: any answer to solve this issue ? I can change the code it's ok with me.

Comment: I would not recommend using a hover effect if this is going to be a mobile website too, since you can not hover on a mobile device

Comment: I think that we can make a custom css for the mobile version to not making it hover right ?

Comment: tapping an element actually fires the hover state in mobiles. If you want to add another layer of insurance you may also add the `:active` state.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
  list-style:none
}
ul.menu{
  width:200px
}
ul.menu li{
  position:relative;
  border:1px #ddd solid;
}
ul.menu li a{
  display:block;
  white-space:nowrap
}
ul.menu li ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
   display:none
}
ul.menu li:hover>ul{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a>menu item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>sub menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>sub menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a>sub menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>menu item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>sub menu item 4</a></li>
      <li><a>sub menu item 5</a></li>
      <li><a>sub menu item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```